# CSS Problem behind content not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Check this: http://42.201.162.12/abd.html

I am not able to click Right Hand side image button search etc

check codes by viewsource and let me know :(

Comment: suspicious link is suspicious

Comment: what do u mean by suspicious, hosted on my PC lol

Comment: Nothing suspicious about that link at all

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes? Do you really think this is a good question?

Comment: It is a completely valid question. The links are in a div which are under the div across the page!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed the top panel above the other item using the `z-index`.

You can fix it by giving the `#head` a higher `z-index` and removing the `background-color`

```
#head {
    top: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #336;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #404040; //REMOVE THIS
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2000;            //ADD THIS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your #toppanel's z-index is 999. That places it over the search button, which is why it is not clickable.
As proof, set your #head element's z-index to 1000 and your search button becomes clickable.

This is surely not what you want, so the correct approach is for #toppanel and #head elements to be part of the same . If use float:right if you want those buttons to float to the right.

Simply placing one div over another as your current implementation does is not really a healthy approach.

Also, if you wish to better learn css, here is a great learning tool, I used this myself and can vouch for it:
http://w3schools.com/

Also, validating your code with the validator tool is a good habit to have:
http://validator.w3.org/